# Broken outline image in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to put an outline around images but on some of the images the outline is broken. Notice the corners in the attached image.

I'm using 5 as the X and Y on the outline. In addition if I use a color besides black, the outline seems to be trying to blend. For example if I set the color to EEC209FF. See 2nd image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What format is the image file? Is the outline done in Unity or external software?

Comment: It's a PNG and I'm using the outline in Unity to add the outline. The image itself doesn't have an outline.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. File for a bug report by going to Help->Report a Bug..

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll file it as a bug.

Comment: do you find any answer? i found this bug too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i'm trying to explain both of your questions:

**Why is the outline shape broken?**

That’s the way the default Unity Outline script works: It just draws your UI.Image 4 time with the defined offset behind your image, it 4 different directions, which is cheap performance trick that fits most needs, but obviously not yours.

You can take a look at the [Outline script on bitbucket here](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/f0c70f707cf09f959ad417049cb070f8e296ffe2/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/VertexModifiers/Outline.cs?at=5.5&fileviewer=file-view-default).

**Why is the outline color partially yellow?**

Unitys Outline Script draws your image in the background and multiplies the color values with your custom color.

That’s why the white part of your image on the upper right edge become yellow in the outline (almost the color you definied EEC209FF).

The outline on the lower right stays greens since it the take the colors from your image edge, approximately [19B754 multiplied with EEC209 to 178B03](http://colorblendy.com/#!/multiply/19b754/eec209), which is a slightly dark green.